# Poisson Sample Mean Wald Test

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, means, hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$, $H_0:\lambda=\lambda_0$, and $H_1:\lambda\neq\lambda_0$ for $\lambda_0>0$. Compute the size $\alpha$ Wald test, estimating $\lambda$ by $\overline{X}_n$.

The size $\alpha$ Wald test rejects $H_0$ if and only if $\left|\tfrac{\hat{\lambda}-\lambda_0}{\operatorname{se}(\hat{\lambda})}\right| > \Phi^{-1}\left(1-\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\right)$. $\hat{\lambda}=\overline{X}_n$, so $\mathbb{V}(\hat{\lambda})=\tfrac{\mathbb{V}(X_i)}{n}=\tfrac{\lambda}{n}$, so $\operatorname{se}(\hat{\lambda})=\sqrt{\tfrac{\lambda}{n}}$, which we can estimate by $\sqrt{\tfrac{\hat{\lambda}}{n}}=\sqrt{\tfrac{\overline{X}_n}{n}}$. I notice in [The Wald test with Poisson distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513812/the-wald-test-with-poisson-distribution) the second answer uses $\sqrt{\tfrac{\lambda_0}{n}}$ instead, which seems fine because we're assuming $H_0$. Of course if we assume $H_0$ completely then we'd know $\lambda=\lambda_0$, but the second answer only assumes $H_0$ partially, if that makes sense. Are both of our methods valid?

Comment: It is impossible to be certain which of the two answers you have in mind when you refer to "the second answer", because which one appears second depends on which one is CURRENTLY the accepted answer, if any, and that can change between the time you post your question above and the time when the reader looks at it, and also depends on how many votes each answer CURRENTLY has, and that can also change during that time.

Comment: dgovanmao’s answer.

Comment: What is it in ngovanmao's answer that causes you to think that it assumes $\text{H}_0$ only partially? $\qquad$

Comment: The denominator is $\sqrt{\tfrac{\lambda}{n}}$, which doesn’t equal $\sqrt{\tfrac{\lambda_0}{n}}$ unless we assume $H_0$.

Comment: That's not what I see when I look at that page.